# how to find satistics of the fitted parameter of an equation

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, equation

For instance: `a`, `b`, `c` and n are the three constants, which are required to be calculated by using data fitting method in a particular equation.

How can I calculate the statistics (mean, standard deviation, variance, skewness value and student t-test value) of the parameters as of a custom equation, for example the quadratic plateau equation?

Example:

```
x=[0,40,80,100,120,150,170,200], 
y=[1865,2855,3608,4057,4343,4389,4415,4478]

y=a*(x+n)^2+b*(x+n)+c, x < xc(Ymax) ....(1)   y=yp, x >= xc(Ymax) ....(2)
```

I have fitted this equation by given code:

```
yf = @(b,x) b(1).*(x+n).^2+b(2)*(x+n)+b(3); B0 = [0.006; 21; 1878];
[Bm,normresm] = fminsearch(@(b) norm(y - yf(b,x)), B0); a=Bm(1);
b=Bm(2); c=Bm(3); xc=(-b/(2*a))-n; p=p=a*(xc+n)^2+b*(xc+n)+c;  
if (x < xc) 
    yfit = a.*(x+n).^2+ b*(x+n)+c;  
else 
    yfit = p;  
end 
plot(x,yfit,'*') 
hold on; plot(x,y); hold off
```

Note: I have already used the `polyfit` command, it was helpful and provided me the results. However, I really don’t find it suitable, as there is no option to customize the equation. Can I find these statistics by any code?

Comment: This is really broad. You've said at the end that `polyfit` works but "isn't suitable". Can you expand on why it isn't suitable? And what you think you're going to gain by using a more bespoke method?

Answer (score 2):

**Questions 1, 2 and 4)** 
Good practice is to set initial values close to the final result if you have previous knowledge about the equation system:

What you have is an overdetermined system of linear equations.

```
y(1) = a*x(1)^2 + b*x(1) + c
y(2) = a*x(2)^2 + b*x(2) + c
y(3) = a*x(3)^2 + b*x(3) + c
…
y(n) = a*x(n)^2 + b*x(n) + c

or in general:
y = A*X, where

A = [a; b; c]
X = [x(1)^2 x(1) 1;
     x(2)^2 x(2) 1;
     x(3)^2 x(2) 1;
     ...
     x(n)^2 x(n) 1]
```

One of the common practices to fit the overdetermined system ([since it has no solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system)) is "[least square fit](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/384740-least-square-fit)" (mldivide,\ (link))

```
x=[0; 40; 80; 100; 120; 150; 170; 200];
y=[1865; 2855; 3608; 4057; 4343; 4389; 4415; 4478];

X = [x.^2 x ones(numel(x),1)];

A = y\X;

a0=A(1); %- initial value for a
b0=A(2); %- initial value for b
c0=A(3); %- initial value for c
```

You can customize equation, when you customize your X and A

but you also can set initial values to ones, it should have neglectable small impact on the result. More related to **Question 4**

```
a0=1;
b0=1; 
c0=1;
```

or to random values

```
rng(10);
A = rand(3,1);

a0=A(1);
b0=A(2); 
c0=A(3);
```

**Question 3 - Statistics**
If you need more control on monitoring of optimization process, use more general form of writing anonymous function (in code below> myfun) to save all intermediate values of parameters (a_iter, b_iter, c_iter)

```
function Fiting_ex()
global a_iter b_iter c_iter
a_iter = 0;
b_iter = 0;
c_iter = 0;
x=[0; 40; 80; 100; 120; 150; 170; 200];
y=[1865; 2855; 3608; 4057; 4343; 4389; 4415; 4478];

X = [x.^2 x ones(numel(x),1)];

A = y\X;

a0=A(1);
b0=A(2); 
c0=A(3);

B0 = [a0; b0; c0];

[Bm,normresm] = fminsearch(@(b) myfun(b,x,y),B0);

a=Bm(1);
b=Bm(2); 
c=Bm(3); 

xc=-b/(2*a); 
p=c-(b^2/(4*a));
yfit = zeros(numel(x),1);
for i=1:numel(x)
    if (x(i) < xc)
        yfit(i) = a.*x(i).^2+ b*x(i)+c;
    else
        yfit(i) = p;
    end
end

plot(x,yfit,'*') 
hold on; 
plot(x,y); 
hold off

% Statistic on optimization process
a_mean = mean(a_iter(2:end)); % mean value
a_var = var(a_iter(2:end)); % variance
a_std = std(a_iter(2:end)); % standard deviation

function f = myfun(Bm, x, y)
global a_iter b_iter c_iter
a_iter = [a_iter Bm(1)];
b_iter = [b_iter Bm(2)]; 
c_iter = [c_iter Bm(3)];

yf = Bm(1)*(x).^2+Bm(2)*(x)+Bm(3); 
a=Bm(1);
b=Bm(2); 
c=Bm(3); 
xc=-b/(2*a); 
p=c-(b^2/(4*a));
yfit = zeros(numel(x),1);
for i=1:numel(x)
    if (x(i) < xc)
        yfit(i) = a.*x(i).^2+ b*x(i)+c;
    else
        yfit(i) = p;
    end
end
f = norm(y - yfit);
```

Comment: @Madhuri , code was updated

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have got mean, standard deviation, and variance from your code. I need to find the standard error and t value for the parameters (a,b and c).

Comment: I got this error while running your given code in MATLABR2013b. function Fiting_ex()
 |
Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.